# Different icon for login / logout

Tags: magento2, frontend, less

I want a different style (background-image) for login / logout in the `.authorization-link` - there seems to be no class-difference whether I am logged in or logged out.

How do I target the login-state in my LESS theme?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use method `$block->isLoggedIn()` to set a custom class for logged in/logged out state.

```
<?php $loggedInState = $block->isLoggedIn()? 'authorization-logged-in': 'authorization-logged-out'; ?>

<li class="authorization-link <?php echo $loggedInState; ?>" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('or')); ?>">
```

Comment: I was thinking they did this already for me :-) Thanks!